# Add new card to existing customer in Stripe using stripe.js only

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I'm using Stripe.js for creating customers,cards and charges everything works like charm but one thing I want to do is add new card to existing customer but I can't proceed further due to an error, below is the example code

```
var customer =  Stripe.Customer.retrieve('cus_xxxxxxxxxx');
customer.Cards.create(card=card_token);
```

**error:** **Cannot read property 'retrieve' of undefined**

Or is there any api which could be helpful to retrieve and create source card directly using ajax call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) is only used to tokenize payment information in the customer's browser.

All other API operations must be done server-side, in the programming language of your choice. Refer to this tutorial to learn more about payment flows with Stripe's API: https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart.

Comment: Ok, so do you mean we can't proceed for create card operation using Stripe.js only ?

Comment: Yes. Integrating directly with Stripe requires a backend server. Stripe.js is only used for tokenizing payment information.